# can I do ssh port forwarding after I've already logged in with ssh?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have an Ubuntu server `example.com` and I have ssh'ed into it. But only after I ssh into it, do I realize that I meant to do `ssh -L 8000:localhost:9000 example.com`. Is there a way to create that tunnel in an already established and running ssh connection?

Comment: So, you have an ssh session open.  Then, if you tunnel, you'll create another one.  You're asking if you can have the tunnel connect to your existing session and replace it?  Presumably to keep your session running?  ... also, why do you want to tunnel if you can just ssh in directly?

Comment: @John: tunnel is very useful to bounce arbitrary protocols over SSH. I mostly bounce RDP.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 8):

If you set your escape character with EscapeChar option in ~/.ssh/config or with the -e option you can.

Assuming an escape of ~: ~C-L 8000:localhost:90000 will do it.